# Array Of Objects Help! Compare Student Name with Test Name and assign score

Tags: c#, arrays, object, search, match

I've been playing around lately for the sake of learning and wanted to ask for some help on a recent program I was messing with. In this program I have Students and Tests. Each student has a test, and I need to the two to be matched. I thought I could create an array of students, and then push a test through the array until a match is found, but I'm honestly stumped on how I can go about doing that.

The purpose of this program is to match Test nameOfStudent with Student name. And then to take the value of Test scoreOfTest and apply it to Student score. 
For Example student1.score = test1.scoreOftest

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main ()
    {
```

Below I create objects for my Student and Test classes

```
        Student student1 = new Student("Finn",0);
        Test test1 = new Test("Finn",100);

        Student student2 = new Student("AJ",0);
        Test test2 = new Test("AJ",97);

        Student student3 = new Student("Sami",0);
        Test test3 = new Test("Sami",80);

        Student student4 = new Student("John",0);
        Test test4 = new Test("John",72);

        Student student5 = new Student("Rey",0);
        Test test5 = new Test("Rey",61);
```

the purpose of this string is to hold the name on the test(in this case "Finn"), and match it to the name of a student. Also I have created an array of Students for the Test to be sent through

```
string nameOnTest = test1.nameOfStudent;

        object[] arrayOfStudents = {student1, student2, student3, student4, student5};
```

I thought if I could create a currentIndex I could do something along the lines of if(currentIndex[i.name] == nameOnTest) then assign score and stop loop

```
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfStudents.Length;i++){
        int currentIndex = i;
        if(currentIndex[object.name] == nameOnTest){
           //then do something similar to
         //  object.score = scoreOfTest   }
       }
    }
}

public class Test {

    public string nameOfStudent;
    public int scoreOfTest;

    public Test(string nameOfStudent, int scoreOfTest){

        this.nameOfStudent = nameOfStudent;
        this.scoreOfTest = scoreOfTest;

    }
}

public class Student {

  public  string name;
  public  int score;

    public Student(string name, int score){

        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;

    }
}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you can look into using Dictionary<object, object> where you can map the student object to each student test, if you would like an example let me know

Comment: Your explanation about problem is not clear... Please put what you are actually trying to do... like "Compare Student Name with Test Name"? Please put proper description.

Comment: check out my solution below: 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29543026/using-array-of-arrays-for-one-to-many-relationship-in-c-sharp/29543693#29543693][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29543026/using-array-of-arrays-for-one-to-many-relationship-in-c-sharp/29543693#29543693

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the code using Linq

```
using System.Linq;
...
...
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Student> students = new List<Student>()
                                 {
                                     new Student("Finn", 0),
                                     new Student("AJ", 0),
                                     new Student("Sami", 0),
                                     new Student("John", 0),
                                     new Student("Rey", 0)
                                 };

    List<Test> tests = new List<Test>()
                                 {
                                     new Test("Finn", 100),
                                     new Test("AJ", 97),
                                     new Test("Sami", 80),
                                     new Test("John", 72),
                                     new Test("Rey", 61)
                                 };

    tests.ForEach(
        t =>
            { students.Where(s => s.name == t.nameOfStudent).FirstOrDefault().score = t.scoreOfTest; });
}
```

Now each student in "students" collection should have the corresponding test score applied.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(currentIndex[object] == Student)
```

correct to

```
if(object[currentIndex] == Student)
```

And, waht is Student? in "== Student", if you declared just class, then it will be equal last declared student.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use LINQ to perform a join operation on the name. Something in the lines of:

students.Join(Tests, x => x.Name, y => y.Name, (x, y) => new {Student = x, Test = y});

If you want to group the all the tests of a particular student, go for a GroupJoin.

Answer (score 0):

This will work. but using Linq will be better

```
        string nameOnTest = test1.nameOfStudent;
        Student[] arrayOfStudents = { student1, student2, student3, student4, student5 };
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfStudents.Length; i++)
        {
            int currentIndex = i;
            if (arrayOfStudents[i].name == nameOnTest)
            {
                arrayOfStudents[i].score = test1.scoreOfTest; 
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your problem then I think you need to match student's from `Student Class` to there Corresponding Score's in the `Test Class`.

You can make use of `Linq Query Expressions`(C# 3.0).It gives you much flexibility and it is easy to read as well.

```
            List<Student> StudentsList = new List<Student>()
            {
                 new Student("Finn", 0),
                                 new Student("AJ", 0),
                                 new Student("Sami", 0),
                                 new Student("John", 0),
                                 new Student("Rey", 0)
            };

            List<Test> TestList = new List<Test>()
                             {
                                 new Test("Finn", 100),
                                 new Test("AJ", 97),
                                 new Test("Sami", 80),
                                 new Test("John", 72),
                                 new Test("Rey", 61)
                             };

            var results = from s in StudentsList
                          join t in TestList
                              on s.name equals t.nameOfStudent
                          orderby s.name
                          select new { Name = s.name, Score = t.scoreOfTest, };

            foreach (var v in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Student ={0} has  Score={1}",
                v.Name, v.Score);
            }
```

It joins on `Name` which is not recommended actually but it's the only thing common between both the classes in your example.