# Using Array of Arrays for One to Many Relationship in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, search, match

I am making a console test with C#.

Actually I have never used of C# but VB.Net. I want to create arrays for one-to-many relationship.

My one is 'A Student' has 'Name','Sex',...,'Courses Taken'.

A Student would take many course, each course has a Title and Included Subject. Each subject has Name, Description and Point.

Like this.

```
Student
- Name   - Sex   - Courses Taken

Take Courses
- Course Title   - Subject Included

Subject
- Subject Name             [Math]       [MVC]
- Subject description      [Advance]    [Building Website]
- Subject Point            [6.9]        [5.6]
```

I want to store each entity in Arrays but I don't know how to connect subjects/courses to each Students. And how can I get Student who attending Math or MVC. Because every students can have more then more course/ more than one subjects.

Comment: Does it have to be arrays? Could you use other data structures?

Comment: Yes. Other Structure like list is ok.


            List<arrCourse> Course = new List<arrCourse>()
            {    new arrCourse{Name="Math",Description="Advance Math1",Point=6.5},
                 new arrCourse{Name="Using MVC .Net for Website",Description="Start MVC",Point=6.5},
            };

Comment: At the risk of sounding unconstructive, C# really isn't the language you want to do this manipulation in. This looks like a job for a SQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like I've done with it in good way...
Pls check my code for my ques! ^^
I first made 3 classes as below..

```
class Students
    {
        public string StudentName;
        public int StudSize;
        public bool StudSex;
        public List<Take_Courses> tcourses;
        public Students() { }
        public Students(string name, int size, bool sex, List<Take_Courses> tcourses)
        {
            StudentName = name;
            StudSize = size;
            StudSex = sex;
            this.tcourses = tcourses;
        }
}
```

and

```
class Take_Courses
    {
        public string classname;
        public List<Arr_Courses> arr_Course;
        public Take_Courses() { }
       public Take_Courses(string classname, List<Arr_Courses> arr_courses)
        {
            this.classname = classname;
            arr_Course = arr_courses;
        }
    }

class Arr_Courses
    {
        public string cosname;
        public string cosdesc;
        public float cospoint;
        public Arr_Courses() { }
        public Arr_Courses(string name, string description, float point)
        {
            cosname = name;
            cosdesc = description;
            cospoint = point;
        }
    }
```

I then initialized values in Main class as below;

```
Arr_Courses acos=new Arr_Courses();
Arr_Courses acos1=new Arr_Courses("Math","Advance Math1",9.5f);

Take_Courses cos=new Take_Courses();
Take_Courses cos_take1=new Take_Courses("Info Tech",new List<Arr_Courses>{acos1});


Students stu=new Students();
Students Stu1 = new Students("Milla", 22, true,new List<Take_Courses>{cos_take1});
```

I then make another List to be generated names of student and use for looping and assign each one to List.

I think some important part is this.

```
  if (arr_stud[i].tcourses[j].arr_Course[k].cosname.Equals("Math"))
    {
         Math_Stud++;
         MathStudents[i] = arr_stud[i];
    }
```

I am sharing this if anyone needs something like this. Any ungraded codes is appreciated to be shared. Thanks so so.

Comment: Avoid usage context when naming classes. `Taken_Courses` could be instantiated as `Taken_Courses availableCourses = new Taken_Courses()` which is confusing; better is `Course` so you can have `Course availableCourse, takenCourse`(your class names should also be singular unless they really represent multiple objects).

Comment: You also probably don't need a `List` of `Arr_Courses` in `Taken_Courses` (I'm assuming `Arr_Courses` represents the course's subject, you should just call it `Subject`) since each course only has one subject. This then allows you to cut back on one `for` loop.

Comment: Finally, LINQ is only slightly less efficient than the most optimized `for` loops, but can be much easier to understand. See my answer for a `Select` query using LINQ.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to create classes to describe your different objects.

```
class Student
{
   string Name { get; set; }
   Gender Sex { get; set; } // write an enum for this
   IEnumerable<Course> CoursesTaken { get; set; }
}

class Course
{
   string Title { get; set; }
   Subject Subject { get; set; }
}

class Subject
{
   string Name { get; set; }
   string Description { get; set; }
   double Points { get; set; }
}
```

Using `List` to create enumerations of instances of these new types allow you to use LINQ to select or evaluate members of the list (nested for loops work as well):

```
// populate a list of students called studentList
//...
// use LINQ to select the students you want
var mathResults = studentList.Where(student => student.CoursesTaken.Any(course => course.Subject.Name == "Math"));
```

Comment: You can even use Entity Framework to build a database from your class models and do your selection in there, where it belongs :)

Comment: Thank you so much! Each word help!

Comment: @Nai Not a problem. Please mark this answer as correct if it is the most helpful.